# Amino acids not in order python

Tags: python

i started learning python recently and i had this project in mind where the code would generate a random nucleotides sequence and then generate its amino acids depending on the nucleotides given. This is the code im using for now but im facing an issu where sometimes the program skips nucelotides (I AM VERY NEW TO CODING)

ex :

CUG CAC CAU GGG UCG

Leu**C**ThrMet**G**Val**G**
instead of

LeuHisHisGlySer

Here is the code i am using, and thanks to anyone that will answer my question !

```
import random
import string
substitute = {
    "A": "T",
    "G": "C",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
}
nuc = 'Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (Brin transcrit)     :'
nucBNT = 'Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (Brin non transcrit) :'
arnM = 'Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (ARN Messager)       :'
AminoA = 'Chaine Acide Aminés                                  :'
nucleotides_length = 90
possible_characters = "ATCG"
random_character_list = [random.choice(possible_characters) for i in range(nucleotides_length)]
random_nucleotides = "".join(random_character_list)
print(nuc, random_nucleotides)
completed_nucleotides = "".join([substitute[c] for c in random_nucleotides])
print(nucBNT, completed_nucleotides)


arn_messager = completed_nucleotides
arn_messager = arn_messager.replace("T","U")
print(arnM, arn_messager)

aminoacids = arn_messager



aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UUU',"Phe")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UUC',"Phe")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UUA',"Leu")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UUG',"Leu")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CUU',"Leu")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CUC',"Leu")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CUA',"Leu")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CUG',"Leu")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AUU',"Ile")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AUC',"Ile")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AUA',"Ile")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AUG',"Met")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GUU',"Val")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GUC',"Val")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GUA',"Val")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GUG',"Val")




aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UCU',"Ser")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UCC',"Ser")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UCA',"Ser")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UCG',"Ser")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CCU',"Pro")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CCC',"Pro")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CCA',"Pro")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CCG',"Pro")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('ACU',"Thr")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('ACC',"Thr")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('ACA',"Thr")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('ACG',"Thr")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GCU',"Ala")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GCC',"Ala")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GCA',"Ala")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GCG',"Ala")




aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UAU',"Tyr")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UAC',"Tyr")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UAA',"---")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UAG',"---")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CAU',"His")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CAC',"His")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CAA',"Gln")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CAG',"Gln")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AAU',"Asn")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AAC',"Asn")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AAA',"Lys")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AAG',"Lys")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GAU',"Asp")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GAC',"Asp")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GAA',"Glu")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GAG',"Glu")




aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UGU',"Cys")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UGC',"Cys")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UGA',"---")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('UGG',"Trp")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CGU',"Arg")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CGC',"Arg")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CGA',"Arg")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('CGG',"Arg")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AGU',"Ser")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AGC',"Ser")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AGA',"Arg")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('AGG',"Arg")

aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GGU',"Gly")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GGC',"Gly")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GGA',"Gly")
aminoacids = aminoacids.replace('GGG',"Gly")



print(AminoA,aminoacids)
```

Comment: What do you mean "skips nucleotides"? Is the example you give the expected output or the actual output? Please [edit] your question to provide both of these and explain in words what is missing. Also, you should learn how to debug, if you haven't already, your code when it doesn't do what you want. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started or to review.

Comment: Some ideas to think about: can amino acids come from overlapping sequences of nucleotides? For example, what amino acids are produced by `UUUC`? How does your code allow for this overlap, if at all? Notice how I'm creating a simple 4-letter example rather than trying to deal with a long, more complicated sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The replace function does not consider the location of the matching string, just that it's there, so it won't look in 3 character intervals, causing some nucleotides to be "cut off."

Since Each amino acid is 3 characters long, you can iterate through your nucleotide sequence 3 characters at a time, replacing appropriately.

**Here's the loop signature for you to play with:**

```
for seq in aminoacids[0 : len(aminoacids) : 3]:
```

Syntax Explanation:
[https://www.techbeamers.com/iterate-strings-python/#:~:text=You%20can%20traverse%20a%20string,to%20iterate%20over%20it%20partially.&text=To%20use%20this%20method%2C%20provide,and%20then%20traverse%20the%20string](https://www.techbeamers.com/iterate-strings-python/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20traverse%20a%20string,to%20iterate%20over%20it%20partially.&text=To%20use%20this%20method%2C%20provide,and%20then%20traverse%20the%20string).

Comment: Sorry for bothering again but this is my first time coding and im having a hard time understanding what i should do and where is should place that loop signature

Comment: @OthmanErrouich You can use loops for running the same kind of code over and over again, or to move through arrays, strings, or anything enumerable. You should learn the fundamentals: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: @CharlesYang Given that OP is a new coder, it might be instructive to expand that loop out instead of using a comprehension (since the meaning can be lost due to the terse syntax). It would also be a good exercise for OP to work out, to get a better understanding of the different ways of expressing loops in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string
substitute = {
    "A": "T",
    "G": "C",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
}
nuc = 'Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (Brin transcrit)     :'
nucBNT = 'Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (Brin non transcrit) :'
arnM = 'Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (ARN Messager)       :'
AminoA = 'Chaine Acide Aminés                                  :'
nucleotides_length = (30)
possible_characters = "ATCG"
random_character_list = [random.choice(possible_characters) for i in range(nucleotides_length)]
random_nucleotides = "".join(random_character_list)
print(nuc, random_nucleotides)
completed_nucleotides = "".join([substitute[c] for c in random_nucleotides])
print(nucBNT, completed_nucleotides)

arn_messager = completed_nucleotides.replace("T","U")
print(arnM, arn_messager)

aminoacids = arn_messager
aminoA = 'Acides aminés correspondant                          :'
if 'UUU' in arn_messager:
    arn_messager.substitute('UUU','Phe')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).